# Rendering a view inside #each

Tags: ember.js

Whenever I try to render a view inside an #each block, I get a PrecompilationError saying: `Compiler said: Error: each doesn't match view`.

Example:

```
{{#each posts}}
  {{view App.MyPost}}
    <div>Some HTML here</div>
  {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

I need to do some stuff when before a single post is rendered, so my guess was that I need a custom view (App.MyPost) to implement the 'willInsertElement' hook. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing a #

If you want to use an inline template, the view helper takes a #

```
{{#each posts}}
  {{#view App.MyPost}}
    <div>Some HTML here</div>
  {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

so it's basically either:

```
{{view App.MyPost}}
```

or:

```
{{#view App.MyPost}}
  <!-- template here -->
{{/view}}
```

Comment: Don't worry about it. it's more of a knowledge than intelligence thing :)